# PHP - Handling discounts in e commerce

Tags: php, performance, database-design, architecture, e-commerce

My question is regarding discounts and promotions used in E-Commerce industry, adding discount on a particular level is easy, lets say I am entering a product which is on 50% off that I can do with simple PHP. What if I have 3 types of products having different discounts.

**EXAMPLE:**

In my example i am using three outlets(NIKE/PUMA/ADIDAS)

**Adidas:** All products are at 50% off.

**PUMA:**   Buy 2 items and get 50% off on the third.

**NIKE:**   Buy one item and get other free.

I have just created random scenarios, but there can by hundreds of brands each having there own criteria of giving discounts. Where should i handle this thing?

My **Database Schema** has two tables regarding product:

**Product table:** having details about a product i.e. name, image, brand

**Product Inventory Table:** having products options i.e. size, color

I hope I made my question clear, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ha i've been totally dealing with this recently. its a pain! obviously its easy if its 50% off because you can apply that per product. its ones like the buy 2 get 50% off the third -- or buy $100 worth of "qualifying" items, get free shipping. in other words you can't just total the cart because you have to validate every item to see if it qualifies.

the only way to do this is look through all the items in the cart. especially if you want to message them -- like if the customer has put two items in the cart -- and now you want to tell the customer the third one will be 50% off. or they have $95 worth of stuff and you want to tell them - buy just $5 more and you get free shipping.

create a promotions table and identify them sequentially: promo01, promo02, promo03 etc 
In the table have separate fields for threshold ("3" items, "100" dollars for free shipping, etc), percent off, the text you will display to customer, etc. You will still need custom code to do final calculations but this helps to organize. it also opens the possibility of making an admin screen to set or change the promotions.

associate the products with the relevant promotion number either directly in the products table with a promotion field, or in another table. if you have promotions that extend across an entire brand then that could be an option as well.

when an item is put into the cart and you get the price etc from the product table - get the promotion number and store it in the cart table.

total your cart. you want the original totals so you can calculate how much they have saved.

check all the cart items for promotions depending on specific threshold etc.

create new totals and sales savings. create sales message.

keep the promotion methods separate from adding an item to the cart - because you will need to run this if they "update" the table by changing a product quantity.

=========

EDIT Its still the same idea if you are doing this for brands and you don't or can't update your product table. Actually in some ways its easier! Have a separate table that just has the Brand Names and the relevant Promotion number.

Customer adds a Nike sneaker to the shopping cart, you look up "Nike" in that table, it has Promo03, so then you add Promo03 to the item information in the cart table (along with product name, price, quantity etc).

THEN you can loop through all of the cart items looking for promotions - lets say the customer has 2 items that are Promo03s - you look that up in the separate promotions table - the threshold for Promo03 is 3 - you then can kick back the appropriate message ("buy one more get half off"). Or if they have bought 3, they have reached the threshold, you apply the discount and create appropriate message ("you get half off your third item")

Comment: i really appreciate your answer, but my case is a bit different like my discounts are dependent on the brands

Comment: its actually easier in some ways with brands because they apply to more products. see edit above...